# Create a binary column for occurence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panadas dataframe which is basically an aggregated view of what happens on a specific day. However not all days are included in a four months window. 
For example,

```
dates = ['2019-02-27', '2019-02-16', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-15']
count_s = [2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'count': count_s})
df["dates_ind"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["dates_ind"])
```

I need to create a new dataframe which has all the days (4 months relative to today). Should the dates correspond between the two dataframes (new and `df`), I need to create a new column of 1's or 0's. If it exists in `df` it should be marked with a 1 else 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `new_df` with `pd.date_range`, then check if the index is in your other `DataFrame`. `pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=4)` gives you calendar month subtraction which will not cross month boundaries when months have different numbers of days.

```
import pandas as pd

today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(today-pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=4),
                                          today, freq='D'))

df_new['exist'] = df_new.index.isin(df.index).astype(int)
```

#### Output: `df_new`

```
            exist
2018-11-06      0
2018-11-07      0
2018-11-08      0
...
2019-02-26      0
2019-02-27      1
2019-02-28      0
2019-03-01      0
2019-03-02      0
2019-03-03      0
2019-03-04      0
2019-03-05      0
2019-03-06      0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
col = df.dates.apply(lambda x: 1 if x in dates else 0)
```

you can replace 'col' with the dataframe column name.

for 4 months relative You could use pd.offsets.MonthBegin and then use an end exclusive daily date range:

```
dts = pd.date_range(month_start, month_start + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1), closed="left")
```

Note that month_start should be a datetime.datetime, and not a string.

Comment: It does not include all the days (4 months relative)